# SUM of column with some text fields

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Looking to see if I can get the SUM of an enter column, including columns that have a symbol and then the number. However the ones with symbols are actually text fields.

```
2
1
- → 2
3
```

Any ideas? I've tried a few different things including using RIGHT, but still sees it as text and doesn't add it.

Comment: Is the arrow apart of the text here? Is there a consistent format to the text fields? Like `[Symbol][#]`? Or is the non-numeric preceding text varying from instance to instance?

Comment: @urdearboy, good questions I should of included. The text fields will always have '- → #' format, unless they have '# → #'. But I only care about the right most number. The arrow is also a part of the text, but not one I'm concerned with grabbing.

Comment: Is it always one digit?

Comment: For example, the =SUM() I'm looking for is one that returns 8 with the example given.

Comment: @ScottCraner max of 2 digits

Comment: Then is there always a space before the number?

Comment: Are you adverse to using a helper column?

Comment: @ScottCraner correct there is.

Comment: @Brotato it's not ideal if I can help it, but acceptable if there's no other way.

Comment: @ScottCraner did you remove the answer bud? It looks like it does work as long as I add the space at the beginning, and replace the hard space. Not sure why that is.

Comment: Are there any singular values stored as text?

Comment: No, these are all stored as numbers and have no problem being sumed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following User Defined Function:

```
Public Function Zum(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim r As Range, s As String, L As Long, i As Long
    Dim numbr As String, CH As String

    Zum = 0
    For Each r In rng
        s = r.Text
        If s <> "" Then
            L = Len(s)
            numbr = ""
            For i = 1 To L
                CH = Mid(s, i, 1)
                If CH Like "[0-9]" Or CH = "." Then
                    numbr = numbr & CH
                End If
            Next i
            If numbr <> "" Then
                Zum = Zum + CDbl(numbr)
            End If
        End If
    Next r
End Function
```

For example:

[image]

It will add cells, but remove anything except digits and the decimal point from the cells before doing the addition.

**EDIT#1:**

This version of the code only handles the **right-most** digits of each cell,

ignoring alphabets and the decimal point:

```
Public Function Zum(rng As Range) As Variant

'   version #2  only sum the right-most digits and ignore the decimal point


    Dim r As Range, s As String, L As Long, i As Long
    Dim numbr As String, CH As String

    Zum = 0
    For Each r In rng
        s = r.Text
        If s <> "" Then
            L = Len(s)
            numbr = ""
            For i = L To 1 Step -1
                CH = Mid(s, i, 1)
                If CH Like "[0-9]" Then
                    numbr = CH & numbr
                Else
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i
            If numbr <> "" Then
                Zum = Zum + CDbl(numbr)
            End If
        End If
    Next r
End Function
```

and if you want only the **single right-most digit**:

```
Public Function Zum(rng As Range) As Variant

'   version #3  only sum the right-most digit and ignore the decimal point


    Dim r As Range, s As String, L As Long, i As Long
    Dim numbr As String, CH As String

    Zum = 0
    For Each r In rng
        s = r.Text
        If s <> "" Then
            CH = Right(s, 1)
            If CH Like "[0-9]" Then
                Zum = Zum + CLng(CH)
            End If
        End If
    Next r
End Function
```

Comment: Something may be a little funky with that.. my sum should be 38 on one set, but somehow it gave me 3676

Comment: If you have something like # -> # wouldn't it take ## as the thing to add instead of just the last digit?

Comment: @Brotato ***YES*** the code keeps **all** decimal digits!

Comment: @Gary'sStudent there are no decimals though, OP just wanted to sum the right most numbers

Comment: @Brotato is correct. There shouldn't be any decimals, but there are instances where there are two numbers, and only the right most applies.

Comment: @DylanColeDuke  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: @Brotato  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Looks like Edit 1 actually worked exactly as needed! Perfect, thanks @Gary'sStudent!

Answer (score 0):

This one requires you to slide this all the way down as a helper column but you can just sum that column after. It assumes that there will be at most one character at the beginning followed by the spaces and arrows before the desired number. Let me know if this isn't what you expected.

`=IF(MID(A11,3,1)="→", --RIGHT(A11,LEN(A11)-4),A11)`

This might work more reliably so long as it is at most 2 digits for the second number
`=IF(ISERR(SEARCH("→",A1)),A1,--RIGHT(A1,2))`

EDIT: This should take care of the non-values, but Scott's answer seems much closer to what you wanted. I'm not sure how you would edit his to make it take into account the non-value cells though.

`=IF(ISNUMBER(A4),A4,IF(MID(A4,3,1)="→", IFERROR(--RIGHT(A4,LEN(A4)-4),"")),"")`

Comment: Looks like that ended up providing a negative value for the symbol fields. 

2
1
-2
3

Other than that, I did fail to mention that some fields do provide no value and are marked if so '-'. When they're marked with that dash, looks like is passes an error on this, and in turn the SUM is error-ed.

Comment: So some fields will have the arrow but not have any values? I misread the question at first, but I removed a negative sign so it always comes out positive. So some data will look like `# → `?

Comment: 2 |
1 |
- → 2 |
3 |
- |
13 |
For example

Comment: @DylanColeDuke I've added a check to see if it's numeric first try now.

Comment: Looks like that's providing a blank on the ones with values unfortunately.

Comment: If you're pasting this in B4 and dragging up or down and it's giving you blanks on values, I'm a little stumped.